# Comprobar si "etiqueta" se encuentra disponible y mostrarla en un SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Realizo un sistema que básicamente es una bitácora de equipos a préstamo. Lo que pretendo que haga es que los usuarios que necesiten un equipo a préstamo realicen un registro, lo cual *es necesario hacer una validación si el equipo esta disponible o no para su uso, y solo aparezcan en los `SELECT` los equipos disponibles*.

Mi tabla principal `prestamo` está compuesta por llaves foráneas. Tengo campos tipo `NULL` ya que esos campos tiene que ver, o mejor dicho, se modifican o llenará el administrador cuando el usuario regrese el equipo (en otro formulario de edición de préstamo).

**Aquí la estructura de mi tabla `prestamo`:**

```
id_prestamo      int(15)          Primaria    
id_etiqueta      int(15)          FK         UNIQUE 
fecha1           date
hora1            time
id_usuario       int(15)          FK
id_departamento  int(15)          FK
id_entrega       int(15)          FK          
fecha2           date                         NULL
hora2            time                         NULL
id_ingeniero     int(15)          FK          NULL
```

La validación que necesito que realice es sobre el campo `id_etiqueta` y sobre `id_ entrega`, que se encuentra en la tabla `prestamo` (antes mencionada).

**Estructura  tabla etiqueta**

```
 id_etiqueta    int(15)         Primaria
 descripcion    varchar(50)
```

**Estructura tabla `entrega`:**

```
 id_entrega     int(15)         Primaria
 descripcion    varchar(50)
```

**Un ejemplo es:**

Si mi campo `id_etiqueta = 1` (`1` equivale a `LAP-01`) lo compare con el `id_entrega = 1` (`1` equivale a `OCUPADO`).

Entonces **NO** mostrará esa etiqueta en el `SELECT` de `id_etiqueta` para que los usuarios no lo puedan visualizar.

Esto con el fin de que no lo puedan ocupar, hasta que se cambie de `id_entrega = 2` (`2` equivale a `Disponible`), aquí es cuando aparecerá nuevamente en el `SELECT` de etiqueta.

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");

 if (
    false === empty($_POST['id_etiqueta'])
    && false === empty($_POST['fecha1'])
    && false === empty($_POST['hora1'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_usuario'])
    && false === empty($_POST['id_departamento'])

) {
    /* Preparamos la consulta usando ? para insertar los valores */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        INSERT INTO prestamo (
            id_etiqueta,
            fecha1,
            hora1,
            id_usuario,
            id_departamento       
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?
        )
    ");
    /* Comprobamos si hubo problemas con la preparación de la consulta */
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die($mysqli->error);
    }
    /* Asignamos las variables, no es necesario crear variables intermedias */
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss',
        $_POST['id_etiqueta'],
        $_POST['fecha1'],
        $_POST['hora1'],
        $_POST['id_usuario'],
        $_POST['id_departamento']   
    );
    /* Comprobamos si se pudo realizar la consulta */
    if($stmt->execute() === true) {
        $mensaje = "Registro agregado correctamente";
    } else {
        /* Comprobamos si hubo duplicidad de registro (clave duplicada) */
        if ($stmt->errno === 1062) {
            $mensaje = "Error:\nRegistro duplicado";
        } else {
            $mensaje = "Error al ingresar:\n" . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
    /* Enviamos al navegador de manera segura el mensaje de texto */
    echo '<script>alert(', json_encode($mensaje), ')</script>';
}
?>
```

**`Select id_etiqueta`**

Aquí inserto a mi base de datos por ID, ya que es llave foránea y lo muestro por descripción al usuario:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_etiqueta" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Equipo Disponible:</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT e.id_etiqueta, e.descripcion 
FROM etiqueta e
INNER JOIN prestamo p on p.id_etiqueta=e.id_etiqueta
WHERE p.id_entrega!=1";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_etiqueta]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   

}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">


<select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_etiqueta" name="id_etiqueta" placeholder="Etiqueta" required>
<option value="-">Selecciona Equipo Disponible</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select></div>
```

Comment: si he entendido la lógica de tu consulta, le añades al SELECT la condición "... WHERE id_entrega=2" o "... WHERE id_entrega!=1" que implica que el equipo está libre.

Comment: @Carmen Buenos días, si es correcta ese consulta pero no se como mostrar en el select de etiqueta (id_etiqueta) solo los que estén disponibles es decir id_entrega=2 para que esos  equipos los usuarios lo puedan ocupar

Comment: necesitas un JOIN con la tabla préstamo, prueba la respuesta que puse a ver si te vale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recoger sólo los equipos libres, simplemente pregunta que no esté ocupado (=2) o para cubrir aquellos que no se han asignado que no estén ocupados (!=1).

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT e.id_etiqueta,
  e.descripcion 
FROM etiqueta e
INNER JOIN prestamo p
  ON p.id_etiqueta = e.id_etiqueta
WHERE p.id_entrega != 1
```

Y en PHP cambia la línea que rellena `$option`:

```
$option .= "<option value='"
  . htmlspecialchars($row["id_etiqueta"]) . "'>"
  . htmlspecialchars($row["descripcion"])
  . "</option>";
```

Comment: esta consulta si me funciona directo en mi SQL pero al implementarla en mi select (añadí el código) ya no muestra nada, modifico el codigo del sql, tal vez lo hago mal

Comment: listo ya edite el select de id_etiqueta

Comment: @Carlos te añadí una edición de la línea option con las comillas corregidas para que te lo muestre en el select.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda... seguiré aprendiendo del arte de la programación

Comment: ¿Eso quiere decir que tienes en la tabla etiqueta elementos que pueden no aparecer en la tabla préstamo? En ese caso hace un LEFT JOIN en lugar de un INNER JOIN y la condicion es WHERE p.id_entrega!=1 OR p.id_entrega IS NULL

Comment: Un placer Carlos, para eso estamos :)

Comment: Me alegra saber que te han solucionado el problema @Carlos. Voy a editar la respuesta para corregir problemas de [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) que sufre.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Estimado, muchas gracias

Comment: También he votado positivamente la respuesta. Es una buena costumbre dejar un voto positivo a aquellas respuestas que te hayan ayudado, sean a una pregunta planteada por ti o por otras personas. Ya tienes reputación suficiente para votar :)